# How to validate google oauth2 token from java code

Tags: oauth, token

I have an android application and web-server working together. Now I want user log in via google from android application (or use one of the google accounts on android). Then andriod application passes token to my web-server with service call... and here I can't realise how to get user email or profile data from google having that token.

I can make a call like this in my browser: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={accessToken}

But how to do that using google libraries? What library to use and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which service you try to use, just pick the right one of [Google's Client Libraries](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs) and check out the [Google+ Sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/SampleProgram#Google+_Sample).

The first half should be basically the same for all APIs. For getting the User info, you would need the [`oauth2` library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#oauth2) and then do something like this (taken from [this example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/oauth2-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/oauth2/cmdline/OAuth2Sample.java?repo=samples)):

```
// Set up the HTTP transport and JSON factory
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

// Set up OAuth 2.0 access of protected resources
// using the refresh and access tokens, automatically
// refreshing the access token when it expires
GoogleAccessProtectedResource requestInitializer =
    new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(accessToken, httpTransport,
    jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret, refreshToken);

// set up global Oauth2 instance
Oauth2 oauth2 = new Oauth2.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, requestInitializer)
    .setApplicationName("Google-OAuth2Sample/1.0").build();

Userinfo userinfo = oauth2.userinfo().get().execute();
```

Comment: Also note, that [`GoogleAccessProtectedResource` is marked as deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543084/calendar-api-and-oauth/11543580#11543580).

Answer (score 1):

I used the code sample from here: https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-verifytoken-java which seem to be more up to date. The code ended up being something like:

```java
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken( accessToken );
Oauth2 oauth2 = new Oauth2.Builder(
    UrlFetchTransport.getDefaultInstance(),
    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential )
    .build();
Tokeninfo tokenInfo = oauth2.tokeninfo().setAccessToken( accessToken ).execute();

// ... check tokeninfo expiry and issued to etc ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need this library [google-api-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client) JAR. Here is the working code how to do it. Keep Handy your ID_TOKEN and CLIENT_ID.

```
String jwt = "YOUR_ID_TOKEN";
GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),new GsonFactory())
                        .setAudience(Collections.singletonList("YOUR_CLIENT_ID"))
                        .build();
        
    GoogleIdToken idToken;
        
    try {
          idToken = verifier.verify(jwt);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Cannot verify the ID_TOKEN send :" + e.getMessage());
        }
        
    if(idToken == null){
          throw new RuntimeException("Failed to verify the ID_TOKEN send");
        }
        
    String username =  idToken.getPayload().getEmail();
```