# Calendar API and OAuth

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

From a lot of examples on the web, i am trying out a calendar application on my own. These examples used **GoogleAccessProtectedResource** during the calendar build. But when I tried it it says its been deprecated. Can someone please tell me what is the correct way to implement this?

```
public static Calendar build(String accessToken) {
  HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
  JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
  GoogleAccessProtectedResource accessProtectedResource =
      new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(accessToken);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javadocs for the [current version of the Google API JAVA Client library](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.10.3-beta/index.html?com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/draft10/GoogleAccessProtectedResource.html) say this:

> Deprecated. (scheduled to be removed in 1.11) Use [GoogleCredential](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.10.3-beta/index.html?com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.html)

See the [Google OAuth wiki pages](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Credential_and_Credential_Store) for an example on how to use it:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
Plus plus = Plus.builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory())
    .setApplicationName("Google-PlusSample/1.0")
    .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
    .build();
```

Comment: has there been any change in AccountManager.getAuthToken call? I have tried all this with my API level as 11 but now when i was trying with API 16, even getAuthToken has been depreceated and/or its available targeted only at level 16. Please let me know if i am incoherent

Comment: They added a new parameter `Bundle options` (which however may be `null`) to the method and deprecated the one without that parameter as of API level 14: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29